# How to calculate the average of multiple iterations using python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

Below is a table with results from multiple runs of different scenario ( like Test_2k, Result_2k, Test_1K, Result_5k). I need to calculate the average score for each scenario as shown in the table.
Could you please suggest how can we calculate the average score for each scenario as in below table using python?

[image]

Comment: You should include any code you've already tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the scenario by ignoring everything after the last "_" in the scenario column, then `groupby`:

```
df["Average"] = df.groupby(df["Scenario"].str.rsplit(pat="_",n=1,expand=True)[0])["Score"].transform("mean")


>>> df
        Scenario   Score   Average
0     Test_2k_R1  0.1095  0.456360
1     Test_2k_R2  0.7399  0.456360
2     Test_2k_R3  0.7521  0.456360
3     Test_2k_R4  0.0200  0.456360
4     Test_2k_R5  0.6603  0.456360
5     Test_5k_R1  0.6839  0.490467
6     Test_5k_R2  0.5649  0.490467
7     Test_5k_R3  0.2226  0.490467
8   Result_2k_R1  0.3966  0.553400
9   Result_2k_R2  0.7102  0.553400
10  Result_5k_R5  0.8727  0.538967
11  Result_5k_R3  0.1931  0.538967
12  Result_5k_R7  0.5511  0.538967
13    Test_1k_R9  0.4124  0.299950
14    Test_1k_R1  0.5594  0.299950
15    Test_1k_R$  0.1663  0.299950
16   Test_1k_R12  0.0617  0.299950
```

Comment: Very nice and pythonist @not_speshal.

Comment: @tlentali - Appreciate it! :)